# Triggering a Gtk+ menu bar on hover

Tags: menu, pygtk, gtk

I've writing a Gnome window-switcher applet in PyGtk+ using menu items to represent the different applications running on the desktop. One thing I'd like to do is to activate the menu item under the cursor when I hover over the menubar. I can connect to the 'enter-notify-event' on the menu bar, but I don't know what to when it is triggered.

So that's my question, how can I make the submenus of the menu bar open when I hover over their parent items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
event = gtk.gdk.Event(gtk.gdk.BUTTON_RELEASE)
event.window = enter_event.window
event.x = enter_event.x
event.y = enter_event.y
event.button = 1
menu.emit('button_release_event', event)
```

It will create a new event object, set it up using the `enter_event` from your `enter-notify-event` and then emit it on your `menu`.

You can read more on events here:
http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gdkevent.html

Comment: This *almost* works. I'm not sure whether I should be watching for enter/leave events on the gtk.MenuBar, gtk.MenuItem or gtk.Menu . Using the above code with the MenuBar doesn't do anything, replacing with BUTTON_PRESS and button-press-event works, but it causes a segfault after moving the cursor off and on the menu a few times. Commenting out the creation of the button press event stops the crash so it's the creation of the event causing the segfault.

Comment: Ignore that, the crash is caused by me calling MenuBar.cancel() in the leave notify event. I'll try and work around that, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can emulate the click event in the location of entering.

Comment: Do you know how to do that? I've been looking and I can't figure it out (I'm reasonably new to Gtk+).